# Firefox Profile Missing Error

Tags: firefox

An error pops up saying my firefox profile is missing. I have made three diffrent ones so I can assure that it is there. I'm assuming it is because I am on a public pc?

Comment: I guess you are talking about the TorBrowserBundle... are you? You are not supposed to start Firefox directly, use "Start Tor Browser" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the Tor Browser Bundle
Redownload the latest bundle, then extract it into a different location than your current one. Start the Tor Browser, don't start Firefox directly.

Sometimes, especially if you've updated Tor Browser Bundle, extracting an update directly on top can cause issues with Firefox.